# Is remembering essential to coding?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I suppose it's not a specific programming question, but it is a question about programming nonetheless.

While I completely understand all the code that i read in the book that I'm using (I have even figured out an error in the book that I fixed my self, within seconds just by looking at it)there are things in there that I'm sort of remembering without really .. thinking about it.

I guess my question is, is it essential to remember some code, or is it a bad practice?

Again, I'm sorry if this is a waste of time to anyone, I'm only trying to learn as much as I can about programming and instilling good habits is important.

I know that Understanding code is much better, and It's what I did when I was learning objective-c , I literally stopped remembering code and wanted to understand it instead of just remember, and it worked. Now that I'm working with Cocos2D, It sometimes feels like I'm remembering instead of understanding, if that makes any sense.. Although since I know Objective-C now, I understand the code, but the order in which it is written.. I'm sort of relying on memory..

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Indeed, it appears that it would. Thanks Marvin, I didn't know of said site. I'll visit that too while keeping an eye on this thread.

Comment: i have a terrible memory, but i don't find that gets in the way too much. understanding is very important.. i think if you come across something that's confusing you should take some time to try to figure it out. you might not remember the exact details, but that's what google is for :)